# How can I do these operations in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, rust

So what I'm trying to do

```
use std::io::{self, Read, Write};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

use termion::color;
use termion::event::Key;
use termion::input::TermRead;
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;

use chrono::{DateTime, TimeZone, Utc};

fn main() {
    // Initialize stdios.
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let stdout = stdout.lock();
    let mut stdout = stdout.into_raw_mode().unwrap();

    let stdin = termion::async_stdin();
    let mut keys = stdin.keys();

    let period = 30;
    let mut scheduled_time = Utc::now().timestamp() + period;

    loop {
        let now = Utc::now().timestamp();
        if now > scheduled_time {
            foo(); // Do some operations,
                   // this function needs to be called in fixed period of time.
                   // eg. per 30 seconds or per 1 hour.
            scheduled_time += period;
        }
        write!(stdout, "Log after foo is done\r\n").unwrap();
        stdout.flush().unwrap();
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(period as u64 - 1)); // Wait for some fixed time to perform foo again.
                                                    // In this example it is 30 seconds.


        // Check for input from user in parallel, by using termion's AsyncReader this does not block.
        match keys.next() {
            Some(Ok(Key::Char('q'))) => break,
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}
```

First 8-10 lines is initializing stdios.

In my main loop. I want to call a function `foo` and do some operations.
But, it needs to be called in some period of time. That is why
I inserted `thread::sleep` function there. Because if I don't call `thread::sleep`,
It will constantly check condition and will not call `foo`.
And that causes 100% CPU usage all the time.

However sleeping caused another problem. Let's say that period was 1 hour. If the user wants
to quit the program in the middle of the sleep. It does not quit until the thread wakes (I guess).

I'm very unfamiliar with threads but I need some idea about how to do this.
I know a little about `AsyncReader`. I guess it creates a thread to not block main thread
while waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the line `let mut stdout = stdout.into_raw_mode().unwrap();` is telling stdout to use raw mode, which disables the TTY device's processing of input characters.  Commenting out that line (and making the previous stdout definition mutable) will allow a ^C interrupt to kill the process.

Even though it is the stdout device being put into raw mode, the file pointer for stdout and stdin are often pointing to the same file (unless they've been redirected), so putting stdout in raw mode seems to be affecting stdin as well.  The TTY drivers in the OS are usually responsible for converting the ^C character into a SIGINT signal, which is sent to your process, which will normally terminate the process

Comment: By putting stdout into raw mode. The input is not given out and there is no line buffering. It reads byte by byte. Thus If I press only `q`, program will exit. And that seemed good idea to me.

Sorry for my ignorance but SIGINT signal seems a bit forceful to me. Is it good way to exit program all the time? What will happen if I hit ^C when the program executing `foo` function.

Thank you for responding.

Comment: It is rather forceful, but unfortunately the only way to interrupt a sleep syscall is to send a signal to the process (which you can override by registering a signal handler).  What you probably want is to use something other than sleep though.  You can use alarm(), which will send SIGALRM after the timeout, and then block on reading input in the mean time, or you can use another thread (one to read input and one to sleep on), or use the select() syscall or something like it to both wait for input and a timeout at once, or you can use async.  Which is best depends on what you're trying to do

Comment: Maybe async is the answer. I should start learning the fundamentals of async before reaching to conclusion.